# Extend std::function to disambiguate overloaded function

Tags: c++, c++14, overloading, std-function

Current `std::function` does not disambiguate overloaded function (see the example at the end). Consequently, when constructing or assigning from an overloaded function, users have to disambiguate manually (with an explicit cast for example), which is annoying. Since `std::function` has function signature information, it can actually disambiguate automatically. So, I tried to make such a new `function` out of `std::function`, and ended up with the following code. Extending the standard library can be tricky and error-prone. So, I'm wondering whether I'm missing something, or a better solution exists. Specifically, it it OK for me to partial-specialize `std::uses_allocator` for my new `function`? (original version of the code can be found [here](https://github.com/Lingxi-Li/CPP_Utility/blob/master/cppu/functional.hpp#L21))

```
template <typename R, typename... Args>
class function<R(Args...)> : public std::function<R(Args...)> {
private:
  template <typename F_, typename F = std::decay_t<F_>>
  using enable_if_fn_t = std::enable_if_t<
                           std::is_same<R, std::result_of_t<F(Args...)>>
                           ::value>;

public:
  using base = std::function<R(Args...)>;

  function(R(*ptr)(Args...)) : base{ptr} {}
  function() = default;
  function(std::nullptr_t) : base{nullptr} {}
  template <typename F, typename = enable_if_fn_t<F>>
  function(F f) : base{std::move(f)} {}
  template <typename Alloc>
  function(std::allocator_arg_t tag, const Alloc& alloc)
      : base{tag, alloc} {}
  template <typename Alloc>
  function(std::allocator_arg_t tag, const Alloc& alloc, std::nullptr_t)
      : base{tag, alloc, nullptr} {}
  template <typename F, typename Alloc, typename = enable_if_fn_t<F>>
  function(std::allocator_arg_t tag, const Alloc& alloc, F f)
      : base{tag, alloc, std::move(f)} {}
  template <typename Alloc>
  function(std::allocator_arg_t tag, const Alloc& alloc, const function& other)
      : base{tag, alloc, static_cast<const base&>(other)} {}
  template <typename Alloc>
  function(std::allocator_arg_t tag, const Alloc& alloc, function&& other)
      : base{tag, alloc, std::move(static_cast<base&>(other))} {}

  function& operator =(R(*ptr)(Args...)) {
    base::operator =(ptr);
    return *this;
  }
  function& operator =(std::nullptr_t) {
    base::operator =(nullptr);
    return *this;
  }
  template <typename F, typename = enable_if_fn_t<F>>
  function& operator =(F&& f) {
    base::operator =(std::forward<F>(f));
    return *this;
  }
  template <typename F, typename = enable_if_fn_t<F>>
  function& operator =(std::reference_wrapper<F> f) {
    base::operator =(f);
    return *this;
  }
};

namespace std {

template <typename R, typename... Args, typename Alloc>
struct uses_allocator<::function<R(Args...)>, Alloc> : true_type {};

}
```

An example:

```
void func(int) {}
void func(char) {}

int main() {
  // std::function<void(int)> f = func; // construction not OK
  // f = func; // assignment not OK
  function<void(int)> f = func; // construction OK
  f = func; // assignment OK
}
```

Comment: Try http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ Instead.

Comment: is the "disambiguate" part already contained in the above code?

Comment: @m.s. Yes. Note the `R(*ptr)(Args...)`parameter.

Comment: could you add an example on how to use this?

Comment: @m.s. Example added at the end. Thanks for the interest. Note that, for the code to be compilable, you also need the master template declaration `template <typename> class function;`.

Comment: @JameyD Rather than being normal user code, this code extends the standard library. So I guess it fits in here, more or less.

Comment: Certainly not the way you are doing it (your `uses_allocator` specialization would be for `std::function`, not yours). And this is badly broken in other ways. `std::function`'s constructor is constrained for a reason.

Comment: @T.C. *your uses_allocator specialization would be for std::function, not yours* Sorry for the typo, fixed. *std::function's constructor is constrained for a reason.* Since I forwarded the arguments to the base constructor, I guess any constraints of `std::function` still apply to my `function`. No?

Comment: No. For example, your `function` is, as far as overload resolution is concerned, convertible from everything under the sun.

Comment: @T.C. `function` does not accept functions that do not match the given signature. See [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e3ae5cf6459b39af).

Comment: `void f(function<void()>); void f(std::string); f("as far as overload resolution is concerned");` What part of "as far as overload resolution is concerned"  is hard to understand?

Comment: @T.C. Thanks for staying with me here. Really learned a lot from you. You are my hero~ Just fixed the code. I guess it looks good now :)